# How to convert Square image to landscape or portrait mode using PIL

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, landscape, portrait

I have an square image and I need to create Landscape and Portrait version of that image. How can I do that using PIL library

I have seen transpose method to rotate the image but how do I change the orientation.

Comment: Please show representative input and corresponding output images and your [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: A portrait image is taller than it is wide. A landscape image is wider than it is tall. Rotating a square image can make it neither portrait nor landscape - only rotated but still square.